# Is there a way to store a object immediately to a another classes list?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

Title, I am thinking something like this

```
Shapes s = new Shapes();
Circle c = new Circle("Our", "Parameters");
Rectangle r = new Rectangle("Our", "Parameters");

Shapes.addToList(c); // I don't want to do this for every object I create
Shapes.addToList(r);
```

So I want to add these object to the 'Shapes' list when I initialize a object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass your `Shapes` object to the constructors, add `this` to that object inside the constructors. Maybe have a common ancestor class for `Circle` and `Rectangle` which has this in its constructor to avoid rewriting it.

Comment: I thought about passing in Shapes as a parameter, but I would need to do this for e.g all shapes, which would work, but look awful I suppose.

Comment: Depending on what you need, having each instance know about its "container" is usually a bad pattern, so you wouldn't pass it in the constructor

Comment: Question would be, do you ever need access to `c` or `r`? Could you do `s.add(new Circle())`? Then only deal with `s`?

Comment: I think actually it would make sense it this program, since it's important which category it contains in.

Comment: I suggest that at this point in your experience you don't have the best perspective on what "looks awful" in different programming styles and recommend focusing on clear and correct code even if you think it "looks awful".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, Yeah I suppose it's actually more important if the code is functional and clear 'enough' to run. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Circle and Square both inherit from Shapes, then in Shapes constructor, you could automatically add to your list. In the destructor, you'd want to remove it.import java.util.*;

```
public class Shapes {
    public static List<Shapes> allMyShapes = new ArrayList<Shapes>();

    public Shapes() {
        addToShapes(this);
    }

    static public void addToShapes(Shapes myShape) {
        allMyShapes.add(myShape);
    }

    static public void dump() {
        System.out.printf("Number of shapes stored: %d\n", allMyShapes.size());
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shapes myFirstShape = new Shapes();

        Circle myCircle = new Circle();
        Square mySquare = new Square();

        Shapes.dump();
    }
}
```

I didn't implement the destructor. This only works, of course, if you always want this behavior.